# Not able to pull off simple combination of volume scatter and volume absorbtion: cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I was following ben u's tutorial on Basic Volume Shading.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Ybk0qNFhqw

I was doing OK with "Volume Scatter", but as soon as I put in the "Add Node"
(3 min 46 seconds in tutorial) and then tried to add "Volume Absorption" shader, the cube turned black.

[image: 3 min 46 seconds into tutorial]

I tried this https://blenderartists.org/forum/attachment.php?attachmentid=402469&d=1443634665 but, got the same result.

There must be something very basic that I'm missing but, I don't have a clue what it is.

Would greatly appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: "*There must be something very basic that I'm missing*" You are using a *Color Mix* node to mix two shaders, instead of a *Shader Add*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Wrong Add node

The **Math (Add) node** you are using works with grayscale values (on the left in the image below).

You would like instead to Add a *shading* to another *shading*: you must use the **Add Shader node** you can find in the Shader nodes group (on the right in the following image).

[image]

The color of the input/output socket is always a guide for the correct connection.

Comment: That did it! Even though it was that elemental, I probably would never of figured it out.  Much Obliged!